# Android-FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

Firstly, I'm new to this android programming and I'm not good in English.

I have this code.

```
package to.msn.wings.newtest;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener{
    private Button btSend;
    private EditText editSendata;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the three primary sections of the app. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager} that will display the
     * object collection.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      this.btSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      this.editSendata = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

      this.btSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NameActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", editSendata.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

   }
 });
    // Create an adapter that when requested, will return a fragment
    // representing an object in
    // the collection.
    //
    // ViewPager and its adapters use support library fragments, so we must
    // use
    // getSupportFragmentManager.
    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is
    // no hierarchical
    // parent.
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener
    // for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager
        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select
            // the corresponding tab.
            // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if
            // we have a reference to the
            // Tab.
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the
        // TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
            .setTabListener(this));


    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the primary sections of the app.
     */
    public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int NUM_ITEMS = 3; // number of tabs

    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String tabLabel = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        tabLabel = getString(R.string.label1);
        break;
        case 1:
        tabLabel = getString(R.string.label2);
        break;
        case 2:
        tabLabel = getString(R.string.label3);
        break;
        }

        return tabLabel;
    }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
     */
    public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab1;
        break;
        case 1:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab2;
        break;
        case 2:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab3;
        break;
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }



}
}
```

When I creat OnClickListner , the app will fail and I don't know why. Please help me!

This is my error in Log

```
02-28 00:00:38.700: D/dalvikvm(1499): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4236K/4368K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
02-28 00:00:38.910: D/AndroidRuntime(1499): Shutting down VM
02-28 00:00:38.910: W/dalvikvm(1499): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aa5b90)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): Process: to.msn.wings.newtest, PID: 1499
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{to.msn.wings.newtest/to.msn.wings.newtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at to.msn.wings.newtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-28 00:00:38.950: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     ... 11 more
```

main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Can we see your layout xml please R.layout.main?

Comment: Null Pointer Exception on MainActivity.java line 47. I think btSend is null. Are you sure there is button with id button1 in main.xml?

Comment: Show ur line at where you got NPE. Post your **main** xml layout file

Comment: In you main layout file only ViewPager there? No button is there? And if it is not there it means you surely got NPE because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When I creat OnClickListner, the app will fail and I don't know why
```

Looks line line 47 is

```
this.btSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

You do not have a `Button` with id `button1` in `main.xml`. You get `NullPointerException` as `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout.

Solution :

Make sure `main.xml` has a `Button` with id `button1`.

After looking at the xml layout posted it seems you do not have a Button or a EditText in `main.xml`. You need to have those in `main.xml`.

Edit:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How can I creat button in viewpager?

Comment: @user3363368 not create in viewpager in your `main.xml`. You initialize views in onCreate after setContentView. But you do not have those in xml. So the initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved it.　And I have another problem. When I click button next screen comes out is very slow, do u know why?

Comment: @user3363368 1 problem per post. if this helps accept this answer by clicking on the tick next to it. If you have a new problem post a new question